# How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?

Tags: emacs

In emacs, I want to bind a command to C-i. So I put `(global-set-key "\C-i" 'forward-word)`

in my .emacs file. This works, except now the TAB key is bound to 'forward-word as well.

**How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In short, this should solve the problem for you:

```
(setq local-function-key-map (delq '(kp-tab . [9]) local-function-key-map))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'forward-word)
```

Longer version:

From the emacs lisp documentation on [function keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html):

> In ASCII, C-i and <TAB> are the same
>   character. If the terminal can
>   distinguish between them, Emacs
>   conveys the distinction to Lisp
>   programs by representing the former as
>   the integer 9, and the latter as the
>   symbol tab.
>
> Most of the time, it's not useful to
>   distinguish the two. So normally
>   local-function-key-map (see
>   Translation Keymaps) is set up to map
>   tab into 9. Thus, a key binding for
>   character code 9 (the character C-i)
>   also applies to tab. Likewise for the
>   other symbols in this group. The
>   function read-char likewise converts
>   these events into characters.

So, once you do the following, you can see the difference in the key bindings:

```
(setq local-function-key-map (delq '(kp-tab . [9]) local-function-key-map))

;; this is C-i
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") (lambda () (interactive) (message "C-i"))) 
;; this is <tab> key
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") (lambda () (interactive) (message "<tab>")))
```

Note, each mode sets up the various <kbd>TAB</kbd> bindings differently, so you may need to do customization per mode that you care about.

**Version Dependency**:

The above works for Emacs 23.1.  From the NEWS file:

> Function key sequences are now mapped using `local-function-key-map',
>   a new variable.  This inherits from the global variable function-key-map,
>   which is not used directly any more.

Which means, in versions 22 and earlier, you can get the same effect by using the variable `function-key-map`.  I tested this and found it to work with Emacs 21.

```
(setq local-function-key-map (delq '(kp-tab . [9]) function-key-map))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'forward-word)
```

Comment: When I try this code, I get an error that local-function-key-map is void. Any thoughts on why it would be void?

Comment: @Steve The variable is defined in Emacs 23, I've updated the answer with a version for 22 and earlier.

Comment: This didn't exactly work for me. Without any changes the 'tab' key was left unbounrd. I tried doing a 2nd "global-set-key" for <tab>, which partially solved the problem, but prevented tab from doing completion in the minibuffer. Using Caio's solution below seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 29):

I found this solution, after much pain, lost in the messages archives. It's simple, avoids conflicts with other modes, and is the only which worked for me:

```
;; Translate the problematic keys to the function key Hyper:
(keyboard-translate ?\C-i ?\H-i)
(keyboard-translate ?\C-m ?\H-m)
;; Rebind then accordantly: 
(global-set-key [?\H-m] 'delete-backward-char)
(global-set-key [?\H-i] 'iswitchb-buffer)
```

Answer (score 18):

I recommend the following:

```
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-i") (kbd "H-i"))
(global-set-key (kbd "H-i") 'whatever-you-want)
```

It should work from at least Emacs 23.

This is similar to the keyboard-translate technique in Caio's answer,
but operates at a slightly higher level.

The disadvantage of keyboard-translate is that it will take effect even
when Emacs isn't running read-key-sequence, and in particular `C-q C-i`
will no longer work as a way to insert a literal tab character.

Modifying local-function-key-map doesn't work well, because typically
you want the `<tab>` key to continue doing whatever the current mode has
defined for `TAB`.

Comment: This worked for me when I wanted to rebind C-i.  I couldn't get the method suggested in the accepted answer working exactly right but this way got it.

Comment: Works perfectly for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solution, which is a sort of combination of the previous two, worked for me.  In this particular case, I wanted to reassign C-i to previous-line.  This solution preserves the functionality of TAB in the minibuffer.  Note that TAB needs to be refined locally for the modes you use with a hook:

```
;  As mentioned in the other solution, C-i and TAB are the same character in ASCII.
;  We have to differentiate between the two and reassign each in a roundabout way.

; differentiate tab from C-i
(setq local-function-key-map (delq '(kp-tab . [9]) function-key-map))

;; Translate the problematic key to the function key Hyper:
(keyboard-translate ?\C-i ?\H-i)

;; Rebind accordingly
(global-set-key [?\H-i] 'previous-line)

; Finish by redefining tab for c-mode.
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
 (local-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'indent-for-tab-command)
    )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: None of the methods described in this thread works for me. C-i is still bound to tab. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may help, as it did help me:

Instead of:

`; differentiate tab from C-i
(setq local-function-key-map (delq '(kp-tab . [9]) function-key-map))`

Try:

`(define-key local-function-key-map [tab] nil)`

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own solution before seeing this question:

```
(define-key input-decode-map [#x2000009] [#x6000069]) ; C-S-i
(define-key input-decode-map [#x200000d] [#x600006d]) ; C-S-m
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-i" [#x4000069])
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-m" [#x400006d])
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-[" [#x400005b])
```

The reason this works is, the keycode that the letter key generates is the "real" keycode [on the left], whereas the keycode that tab, enter, escape generate are function key symbols. The function key symbols are already mapped in input-decode-map to the same symbols that the letters naturally generate, and will continue to work.

The keycodes that I mapped them *to* use the same mechanism as keycodes for C-0, etc [i.e. keys that don't have control codes in ASCII]. So, they're described as e.g. C-i (since they're excluded from the special casing that describes them as TAB/etc), and still have event-modifiers/event-basic-type (control)/?i.

The downside is that they're a bit harder to work with - you have to use the numbers, since they won't be generated by (kbd) and you can't call a function or variable within a vector literal. If you bind C-i or C-m to a movement function, it will work with shift selection (since even though they're "fake" keys the mode still knows that C-S-m is shifted and that it's normal equivalent is C-m)

NOTE: This will impact text terminals, so if you use text terminals you will need to detect whether the gui is running with `(when window-system ...)` - if you use the Emacs Daemon with graphical windows you may want to put this in a window-setup-hook.