# How to use ctrl-i for an emacs shortcut without breaking tabs

Tags: emacs, tabs, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792326/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-c-i-without-changing-tab)

I want to redefine the emacs keyboard shortcut control-i to be "MOVE CURSOR UP"

To do this, I added the following line to my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'previous-line)
```

What I then discovered is that the tab key, by default, does whatever is bound to control-i, which is obviously not what I want. So, to restore normal tab behavior, I added this to my .emacs file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'indent-for-tab-command)
```

This mostly works. BUT, tab no longer works for auto-completing commands in the mini buffer. How can I fix that? Or is there a better way of going about this?
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I found something in that thread that seems to work in my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a post in this thread: 
[How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792326/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-c-i-without-changing-tab)

I was able to find a solution:

```
;; Translate the problematic keys to the function key Hyper, 
;; then bind this to the desired ctrl-i behavior
(keyboard-translate ?\C-i ?\H-i)
(global-set-key [?\H-i] 'previous-line)
```

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Control-i</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd> are usually considered the same (in a terminal for instance). However Emacs makes a distinction and allows a separate binding.

See [Emacs TAB and C-i](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabKey).

You can also set a local binding with `(local-set-key key binding)`.
You could create an `(interactive)` command in your `.emacs` that would set the local binding, and call that command only in the buffers of interest.

**Edit**

Example: put this in your `.emacs`, or in a new buffer and then do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`eval-current-buffer`

```
  (defun mybinding () 
    (interactive)
    (local-set-key [tab]
      '(lambda () (interactive)
          (message "hello"))))
```

Then go to a buffer of interest and <kbd>M-x</kbd>`mybinding` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to see the result ("hello" should be displayed as a message in the minibuffer).

Try <kbd>C-f</kbd> to open a new file and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> which has the same completion behavior as usual.

Comment: So if I've understood your suggestion, what I want to do is re-bind the control-i and TAB keys in the local buffer only. This way in the mini-buffer, their default binding would still apply.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, although the solution below seems to work too and is maybe simpler?