# (Emacs) Accidentally Switched Keys, How to reset them back?

Tags: emacs, key, reset, translate, key-bindings

I tried to use "C-i C-f" for a command, but found out "C-i" was the key for TAB.

I tried using translate or something before to switch keys and now when I type "C-i", "H-i" shows up.

I tried (keyboard-translate "H-i" "C-i") and now Tab and "C-i" show Mouse-2

Now I realized that keyboard-translate is probably permanent, is there a way to reset it?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792326/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-c-i-without-changing-tab)

Comment: Emacs? I used to use that a lot in the '80s.

Comment: ...in addition, once you've done that, check out http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/ which describes how to use keys as prefixes.  (And if you haven't used Emacs since the 80s, you've missed out on decades of development of a great and vibrant editor.  Your loss.)

Comment: Oh thanks, that was one of the articles I looked at. However, when I type ctrl+i it shows "H-i" in the minibuffer. Do you have any suggestions? (Thanks again)

Comment: It's pretty unlikely the changes you made were permanent, so just exit and relaunch Emacs.

Comment: Hello, for all the bother. I tried restarting it stays the same, is there a way to reset my key-bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that you've saved your changes using the customisation system. Take a look at your `.emacs` file to see if there's anything that's looks auto added. Possibly `custom-set-varaiables`. Get rid of that and try restarting your editor.

Comment: I'd say that it is sometimes needed to restore the keybind without closing a emacs. I am sometimes do for some reason a wrong keybind, and want to change it's defaults back. If I close the Emacs, I'll lose my session, it isn't good.

Comment: If it is done using customize, you can enter the customisation interface again and remove customisations. That should restore the old keybindings.