# Use TAB for expand and C-i for indent-relative in emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs

how can i use TAB for dexpand and still have C-i for indent-relative?

Im trying: 
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'dabbrev-expand)
(global-set-key "\C-i" 'indent-relative)

but it wont work, because both TAB and C-i are used for dabbrex-expand.

Comment: duplicate of [How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792326/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-c-i-without-changing-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **never** use emacs in terminal then you can do the following

First separate <kbd>C-i</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> by doing

```
(define-key key-translation-map [tab] [?\t])
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-\i] [(control i-key)])
(define-key function-key-map [tab] nil)
(define-key function-key-map [?\t] nil)
```

Then you can bind commands to the keys as usual

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'dabbrev-expand) 
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-i-key>") 'indent-relative)
```

**Credits:** I picked this up from [this comment](http://irreal.org/blog/?p=1546#comment-77260) by [Fuco](https://github.com/Fuco1).